# push and pop information from DetailViewController to MasterViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I'm making a small iPad APP using the SplitViewController and I mainly working with MasterViewController on the DetailViewController. I am trying to Push some data from the DetailViewController to MasterViewController. once the information is pushed to the MasterViewController I want to make use of it so to do this im using a pop method.

The push method populates the array- but for some reason my array is recreated every time i call the `pushModuleTitle` method and it only hold one object at a time.

In the `DetailViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)buttonAddPressed:(id)sender
{
    cw3MasterViewController *master = [[cw3MasterViewController alloc]init];
    [moduleTitles addObject:textFieldModuleTitle.text];
    [master pushModuleTitle:self.textFieldModuleTitle.text];);
}
```

In the `MasterViewController.m`

```
 - (NSMutableArray *)moduleTitleStack//init array
    {
        if (!_moduleTitleStack){
            _moduleTitleStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        return _moduleTitleStack;
    }

    -(void)pushModuleTitle:(NSString*)moduleTitile
    {
        NSString * moduleTitileObject = moduleTitile;
        [self.moduleTitleStack addObject:moduleTitileObject];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.moduleTitleStack);

    }
```

so to use the information pushed I'm using this pop method: - But this alway returns me a null value and when I put a break point it indicates that my moduleTitleStack has 0 objects. I'm not sure why.

```
-(NSString *)popModuleTitle
{
    NSString * moduleTitileObject = [self.moduleTitleStack lastObject];
    if (moduleTitileObject)[self.moduleTitleStack removeLastObject];
    return moduleTitileObject;
}
```

calling the popModuleTitle method: Gives a null value

```
- (IBAction)testButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"%@", [self popModuleTitle]);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the same as the answer to the other question you just asked. You are creating a new instance of cw3MasterViewController every time you click the button. You should get a reference to the master controller like this:

```
cw3MasterViewController *master = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
```

This assumes that master is the only controller at index 0 of the split view controller. If it's embedded in a navigation controller (which it often is), then you would need to go a little further to get to master:

```
cw3MasterViewController *master = (cw3MasterViewController *)[(UINavigationController *) self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0] topViewController];
```

Comment: Where do I pu this line P.S I'm very new to this

Comment: @user2382834, If you want to use this reference in multiple places, then I would create a property for master, and put that line in the detail view controller's viewDidLoad method. BTW, this will only work correctly if the master controller is not embedded in a navigation controller. Is yours? If, so, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Not sure, but I started by creating a Master-Detail Application so everything was set up for me by xcode

Answer (score 0):

### ere :

w3MasterViewController *master = (cw3MasterViewController *)[(UINavigationController *) self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0] topViewController];

you have a Semantic Issue: Subscript requires size of interface 'NSArray', which is not constant in non-fragile ABI

Use Delegation instead !